# How do I read multiple .txt files in to program with Scanner?

Tags: java

I have a program where I read in a .txt file using a scanner, and the code that follows prints out the sum of the integers in the .txt file.

To read in another .txt file to get the sum for that file, I have to manually change the code to point to the new file. I would like to know how I can setup the program so that it will automatically iterate to the next file and print the sum.

I'm using just basic scanner logic to read in the file.

```
Scanner txt = new Scanner(new File("/Users/.../25000.txt"));
        String line = txt.nextLine();
        String[] ne = line.split(" ");
```

I only have two files that I want to do this for: 
1000.txt
25000.txt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an array of file names and then iterate the array e.g.

```
String[] files = { "/Users/.../25000.txt", "/Users/.../35000.txt", "/Users/.../45000.txt" };
for (String file : files) {
    Scanner txt = new Scanner(new File(file));
    String line = txt.nextLine();
    String[] ne = line.split(" ");
    // ...
    txt.close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked exactly how I needed it to!